Is there any way with sqlpackage to exclude encrypted objects, when extracting or publishing?
I'm trying to extract a DACPAC to create a dev version of a database on my local machine.  I've run into a problem: The database contains a scalar function that's encrypted.  When I try to publish the DACPAC to my local machine the publish fails with the error message

The element [dbo].[xxx] cannot be deployed as the script body is encrypted.

(where xxx is the name of the scalar function)
Is there any way to configure sqlpackage to either not extract an encrypted object into a DACPAC or not publish it from a DACPAC?
I know I can exclude all scalar functions when extracting or publishing.  However, I'd like to include all other scalar functions and somehow exclude just the encrypted one.
